# Cast SQLite3 object cursor to a string or list (Python)

Tags: python, sqlite

In a cell of my database I have a list of values. I want to access that values of my database, so I do this:

```
interpretation = db.execute("SELECT interpretation FROM music WHERE ID = ?", (id, ))
```

Intepretation will be a **SQLite3 object cursor** (that "has" my list of values), and I want to convert that object to a list in Python. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Did you try calling `list()` on it?

Comment: I did. The thing is: the list is a list of pairs. I then iterate through that list and try to create a graphic with that pairs using matplotlib. I get some errors when trying to do this, which I didn't get when my list was not taken from the DB, but was already given in the code itself. So, I don't know if list() is just not working, or it is, but it gives a "different" kind of list (if that's possible).

Comment: Show the output of interpretation the output will be in dict form as per my knowledge

Comment: I printed the list (interpretation) on terminal, after calling list(). This is what I got:
http://imgur.com/sLtYhrE